# Why am i receiving so many unsolicited GRE packets?

Tags: iptables, gre

My (linux) server has some fairly simple iptables rules.

```
iptables -A INPUT -p icmp -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -m state --state ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -m tcp -p tcp --dport ssh -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -m tcp -p tcp --dport https -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -j LOG
iptables -A INPUT -j NFLOG
iptables -A INPUT -j DROP
```

ICMP goes unfiltered, but no other uncessessary connections allowed.
The NFLOG rule just stores packets into a packet capture fule (pcap).
Because syslog got quite spammy, i looked into the details of the packets.

`tshark -V -a filesize:1 -r /scooby/doo.pcap` (IPs & Ports `[replaced]`)

```
Frame 1: 52 bytes on wire (416 bits), 52 bytes captured (416 bits)
    Encapsulation type: Raw IP (7)
    [Protocols in frame: raw:ip:gre:ip:udp:data]
Internet Protocol Version 4, Src: [incoming IP] ([incoming IP]), Dst: [my server IP] ([my server IP])
    Version: 4
    Header length: 20 bytes
    Total Length: 52
    Identification: 0x0000 (0)
    Flags: 0x02 (Don't Fragment)
    Time to live: 52
    Protocol: GRE (47)
Generic Routing Encapsulation (IP)
    Flags and Version: 0x0000
    Protocol Type: IP (0x0800)
Internet Protocol Version 4, Src: [not my IP1] ([not my IP1]), Dst: [not my IP2] ([not my IP2])
    Version: 4
    Header length: 20 bytes
    Total Length: 28
    Time to live: 64
    Protocol: UDP (17)
User Datagram Protocol, Src Port: [random port1] ([random port1]), Dst Port: [random port2] ([random port2])
    Length: 8
```

The unsolicited packets are mostly ip:gre:ip:udp packets.
The volume of GRE packets - usually multiple per minute - greatly outweights other unsolicited packets (vulnerability scanners / spammers / port scanners).
None of the IPs inside the GRE encapsulation have any special meaning to me, just various regular IPs belonging to (exclusively) US-based companies (so, not entirely random addresses).

**Why would someone send those GRE packets?**

Are there known DoS vulnerabilities related to GRE packets?
Is this an attemt to fool misonfigured routers/servers into forwarding the encapsulated packets to their apparent destination?
Does the sender try to gather information about the nature of potential GRE tunnels i may have setup?

Bonus: Is the most reasonable reaction really "-j DROP"-ing them?

Comment: How many is 'many' what proportion of the total traffic?

Comment: Do you have any examples of this traffic?

Comment: Exactly what did you redact? Remember that you should [_avoid redacting_](http://meta.serverfault.com/q/963/126632) if possible, especially in a situation like this, as it will only cause confusion.

Comment: That might be so, and that's an additional reason that I suspect that you have redacted too much and therefore will not be able to get an answer.

Comment: I've been seeing an uptick in these every day across all my internet facing VM's.  Not a large amount, but it's probably just some scanner / bot.  Unless you have rules that would permit that protocol and something listening for GRE, then no harm.

Comment: [Here](https://isc.sans.edu/forums/diary/More+on+Protocol+47+denys/21867/) is more detail about the uptick in unsolicited GRE traffic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to Rick Wanner (ISC), such traffic was likely connected to the Mirai botnet. He commented on it [here](https://isc.sans.edu/forums/diary/Increase+in+Protocol+47+denys/21865/) & [here](https://isc.sans.edu/forums/diary/More+on+Protocol+47+denys/21867/) (thanks, @Aaron)
As @Michal Hampton suspected, the addresses contained in the payload are a clue: they appear to match the [pseudo random number generator](https://github.com/jgamblin/Mirai-Source-Code/blob/master/mirai/bot/rand.c) contained in Mirai - though i have been unable to confirm this.

[Brain Krebs says](https://krebsonsecurity.com/2016/09/krebsonsecurity-hit-with-record-ddos/) his website was downed at least to some degree through GRE spam. The reasoning behind sending GRE (ip/47) as opposed to more traditional DDoS methods is not obvious. Speculation on why GRE is used in DDoS:

1. bugs in GRE routers that can be abused to either reflect traffic or map otherwise inaccessible network topology
2. stateful firewalls that include reasonable defaults for icmp/tcp/udp, but choke/misbehave on full pipes of unusual protocols.
3. bad QoS configuration in routers effectively prioritizing DDoS traffic